# I can not find a distribution that uses grub, than will boot for me

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-loader, refind

I have tried many distributions and if they use grub, then they don't work. But if the system is installed with,  rEFInd, then the system starts up and runs. For example, I have attached an error message while installing Ubuntu 20.10. I got a similar one when installing manjaro or mint or deepin or openSUSE or something else, but when I installed arch with systemd-boot, it worked. Next I installed manjaro architect with rEFInd and it also worked, but I need exactly apt, maybe someone knows what to do?

My laptop:
Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IAP
Intel Pentium N4200;
AMD Radeon 530;
4 Gb RAM.

[image: error]

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to best use this site. To get to your question, could you remove the reference to Telegram and edit your post to include information about your hardware. Thank you!

Comment: This user had to do this: Lenovo Ideapad 320 Post #13 install without grub & then use Boot-Repair
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436555

Comment: What exactly stops you from installing Ubuntu or any other Debian-based distribution and then use rEFInd?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't speak russian.
I am pretty sure it's a secureboot / UEFI related issue. Try to go into the BIOS/UEFI and disable secure boot and use the Legacy mode, if possible. Not sure which vendor the BIOS/UEFI has. But you can find more details if you search for this.